# Hybrid angular app with webpack

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, systemjs

I'm trying to migrate angular1 app to angular2 using webpack
All the examples I found for hybrid apps using systemjs
Can I creat an hybrid angular app with webpack without using systemjs?

Comment: Trying to do the same but I can't find a sample

Comment: Sure you can, check @angular-builders/custom-webpack.

Comment: Look at this repository https://github.com/Zadvornyi/angular-hybrid-webpack